# Unable to boot up with Snow Leopard DVD

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, install, startup, dvd

I accidentally deleted my /bin folder. My computer is now permanently stuck at the Apple screen with an infinite spinning indicator.

I have:

1. Inserted my Snow Leopard DVD
2. Held down c - nothing
3. Held down option - shows me Macintosh HD, but then hangs

I am not sure how I can just start fresh and install a clean build of Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bootable flash with Mac OS X, then hold down options and load from that drive. Then just install a clean build as usual.